# Parse string between a pair of delimiters (that are strings)

Tags: c#, .net, superpower

I would like to create a parser using **Superpower** to match strings like:

`<<This is my text>>`

That is, a string delimited by a pair of strings (left and right). In this case, the delimiting strings are `<<` and `>>`.

For now, all I've got is a parser that only works when delimiters are single chars:

```
public static TextParser<TextSpan> SpanBetween(char left, char right)
{
    return Span
        .MatchedBy(Character.Except(right).Many())
        Between(Character.EqualTo(left), Character.EqualTo(right));
}
```

How should I modify it with `left` and `right` being strings instead?

Comment: The work-in-progress `Span.Except(">>")` from [this PR](https://github.com/datalust/superpower/pull/129) seems like it might help?

Comment: I think it could make the trick! Definitely a good addition :D

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public static TextParser<TextSpan> SpanBetween(string left, string right)
{
    return Span
        .MatchedBy(Parse.Not(Span.EqualTo(right)).Then(p => Character.AnyChar).Many())
        .Between(Span.EqualTo(left), Span.EqualTo(right));
}
```

or with `Span.Except`

```cs
public static TextParser<TextSpan> SpanBetween(string left, string right)
{
    return Span
        .MatchedBy(Span.Except(right))
        .Between(Span.EqualTo(left), Span.EqualTo(right));
}
```

I'm assuming, contrary to what your questions says that you want to match text *between* the delimiters, not the entire string, since this is what your example shows.